# Internal groups in Set/I

Tags: category-theory

I have a question. Consider the category $\mathbf{Sets}/I$ sliced over a set $I$. Now we can think of this a group in a category, right?
Now we have to show that such a group $G$ determines an $I$-indexed family of groups $G_i$ by setting $G_i=G^{-1}(i)$ for each $i\in I$. Any tips or hint are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try reducing the problem to "find group objects in $Set^I$", given the equivalence of categories between this and $Set/I$? This is easier, because the former is a functor category, and monoid objects in functor categories are objectwise-monoid functors. The hard part seems to be the definition of the multiplication, but it's classical diagram chasing :-)

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I think that's somewhat accidental because in every category $\mathcal C$ with limits, internal groups in the slice $\mathcal C/X$ have fibers in $\mathcal C/\mathbf 1\cong\mathcal C$ that are group objects. A better hint, I think, is that pullbacks from one slice category to another preserve limits, so in particulary products.